# How To Rectrict Access to the Files in File System(ASP.NET Web application directory)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-io, web-applications, file-permissions

am working on a ASP.Net Web Applications. In that user can upload documents and they can view the same when they required. These uploads kept in the file system(path:- **WebApp/Uploads/Docs**). This will be served to users only if they are the owners of the document Or upload.

My Question Is: The file with this  **WebApp/Uploads/Docs/Doc1.doc**
path must be accessed only by the Uploader/Owner of that document.

Other application user must be restricted from accessing this Path.

So, **Can i have a check(User Is Owner Or Not) before this file served to other users.?**

Answer (score 2):

I will advise you to keep the documents out of the web site directory since this exposes them to an unauthorized downloads.

as for the check that you need you can create a generic handler (*.ashx) for your documents  that will validate the document owner and will serve the content only to permitted users.

[HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: i think this is a good option for me. But one small question arise is: After checking privilege using this handler. we are sending control to the same file path or some error page. When user gets the rite file path, they might try to access it directly rite.? Am i rite.?

Comment: You are not suppose to expose the directory path of your server. The user will get a file buffer and not the path to the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via Web.config
In web.config under  add the  element..

In the  element, add the  configuration element and the  configuration element. Use the users attribute to specify a comma-delimited list of user names. You can use a question mark (?) as a wildcard character that matches any user name. For example, the following code denies access to all users except user1 and user2:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: They might upload a huge number of documents and privilege only for uploader. So i don't think this is a good option.